# Facebook Connect to send SMS to Facebook Friends

Tags: iphone, facebook, sms

I am developing an iPhone application that will send sms the logged in user friends'. I am using FacebookConnect for the same. The problem is I am getting the uid of all friends but what is the way to send SMS to these uids(friends UID).

Thanks,
UPT

---

Please have a look on the following code and I am not able to send the message to friends:
To get friends UID:

```
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
```

//  sessionView = session;

```
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.friends.get" params:params];
```

in delegate:

-(void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result

//doing the following code:

if (@"facebook.friends.get" == request.method) {

```
    NSArray* users = result;

    myList =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: users];

    for(NSInteger i=0;i<[users count];i++) {

        NSDictionary* user = [users objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString* uid = [user objectForKey:@"uid"];

        //          NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:

        //                           @"select name from user where uid == %@", uid];

        //NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];

        //[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];


        NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:uid, @"uid", @"checkSMSCanSend", @"callback", nil];
        [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.sms.canSend" params:params];
    }
```

and for SMS.canSend:
    if (@"facebook.sms.canSend" == request.method) {

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SMS" message:@"User can send SMS successfully." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

But this is not getting called.
Please help to SMS friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to check whether the user can send SMS-s and if you are allowed to:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/sms.canSend

To ask extended permissions you'll call something like this (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions)

```
FBPermissionDialog* dialog = [[[FBPermissionDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.permission = @"sms";
[dialog show];
```

If user has enabled SMS for your application you can send an SMS using

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/sms.send

```
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@"1234", @"uid", @"hellow world", @"message", nil];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.sms.send" params:params];
```

For examples how to call Facebook API methods through iPhone go here: http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk/#readme

***Editing my post to also answer to additional question poster posted as an answer***

Your mistake is here, you are trying to compare strings using == operator.

```
if (@"facebook.friends.get" == request.method)
```

this compares the addresses of two strings. To compare if the string contents are equal you should use `isEqualToString` method:

```
if([@"facebook.friends.get" isEqualToString:request.method])
```

Comment: Sorry for such silly mistake. But by reverting this change still not going inside if..